# Android - directory for running tests on the command line

Tags: android, android-espresso, gradlew

I know how to run tests from Android Studio and it's work, and I want to learn how to use command line.

From guide for Espresso [link](https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/UI-Testing-with-Espresso):
"Note: You can also run the tests on the command line using: ./gradlew connectedDebugAndroidTest"

Should I use cmd.exe for this or I can type commands somewhere in Android Studio?
 In which directory should I run this command?
I have gradle installed with Android Studio and I didn't set enviroments variables for gradle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the terminal from Android Studio. It is placed at bottom and is called "terminal".
To use this command, you will launch at your project directory.

Comment: I find that in Terminal - **gradlew.bat** is for Windows, for other os - **./gradlew**. And my command will be **gradlew.bat connectedDebugAndroidTest**. It works, thanks!